# Problems with merge function

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a us map with the total cases of Covid-19 by state. In order to do that task I have this following code:

```
library(readxl)
library(maptools)
library(spdep)
library(RColorBrewer)

library(sp)
library(sf)

hp_usa_states <- readShapeSpatial("USA_States.shp")
names(shp_usa_states)                              
shp_usa_states@data 

infected <- read_excel("C:/Users/BP2646/Desktop/databaseinfUS/US.xlsx") 
names(infected)
```

I have problems with this part of the code "*(Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column)*"

```
infected_bystate <- shp_usa_states
    infected_bystate@data <- merge(shp_usa_states@data,infected,by.x= "Cases",by.y="Cases",all.x = TRUE,sort  = FALSE)
    summary(infected_bystate)
```

I have this problem:
*Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column*

I don't know why.
This is my dataset:

```
structure(list(State = c("Arizona", "California", "Colorado", 
"Connecticut", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", 
"Hawaii", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky[384][385]", 
"Lousiana", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", 
"Missouri", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", 
"New York", "North Carolina", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", "Pennsylvania", 
"Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "Soth Dakota", "Tennessee", 
"Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "Wisconsin", 
"Total"), Cases = c(6, 157, 18, 2, 4, 28, 22, 2, 19, 6, 13, 1, 
8, 6, 9, 92, 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 5, 15, 176, 7, 3, 2, 15, 14, 5, 9, 
5, 7, 21, 2, 1, 9, 275, 3, 976), Recovered = c(1, 6, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 12), Deceased = c(0, 3, 
0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 24, 0, 31), Remaining = c(5, 
148, 18, 2, 4, 26, 22, 2, 17, 6, 13, 1, 8, 6, 9, 91, 2, 3, 1, 
5, 4, 5, 14, 176, 7, 3, 2, 15, 14, 5, 9, 4, 7, 21, 2, 1, 9, 250, 
2, 933)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

This is the second data frame:

```
structure(list(STATE_NAME = structure(c(48L, 27L, 20L, 35L, 42L, 
51L, 50L, 13L, 46L, 24L, 38L, 30L, 16L, 22L, 28L, 33L, 39L, 7L, 
40L, 31L, 15L, 29L, 45L, 5L, 36L, 14L, 9L, 8L, 49L, 21L, 6L, 
18L, 17L, 47L, 26L, 3L, 37L, 34L, 43L, 44L, 32L, 1L, 25L, 11L, 
41L, 4L, 19L, 10L, 23L, 12L, 2L), .Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", 
"Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", 
"Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", 
"Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", 
"Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", 
"Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", 
"North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
"Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", 
"West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), class = "factor"), 
    STATE_FIPS = structure(c(48L, 27L, 20L, 35L, 42L, 51L, 50L, 
    13L, 46L, 24L, 38L, 30L, 16L, 22L, 28L, 33L, 39L, 7L, 40L, 
    31L, 15L, 29L, 45L, 5L, 36L, 14L, 9L, 8L, 49L, 21L, 6L, 18L, 
    17L, 47L, 26L, 3L, 37L, 34L, 43L, 44L, 32L, 1L, 25L, 11L, 
    41L, 4L, 19L, 10L, 23L, 12L, 2L), .Label = c("01", "02", 
    "04", "05", "06", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12", "13", "15", 
    "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", 
    "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", 
    "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "44", "45", "46", 
    "47", "48", "49", "50", "51", "53", "54", "55", "56"), class = "factor"), 
    STATE_ABBR = structure(c(48L, 27L, 22L, 29L, 42L, 51L, 49L, 
    14L, 47L, 24L, 38L, 31L, 13L, 20L, 30L, 35L, 39L, 7L, 40L, 
    32L, 16L, 34L, 45L, 5L, 36L, 15L, 8L, 9L, 50L, 21L, 6L, 18L, 
    17L, 46L, 25L, 4L, 37L, 28L, 43L, 44L, 33L, 2L, 26L, 11L, 
    41L, 3L, 19L, 10L, 23L, 12L, 1L), .Label = c("AK", "AL", 
    "AR", "AZ", "CA", "CO", "CT", "DC", "DE", "FL", "GA", "HI", 
    "IA", "ID", "IL", "IN", "KS", "KY", "LA", "MA", "MD", "ME", 
    "MI", "MN", "MO", "MS", "MT", "NC", "ND", "NE", "NH", "NJ", 
    "NM", "NV", "NY", "OH", "OK", "OR", "PA", "RI", "SC", "SD", 
    "TN", "TX", "UT", "VA", "VT", "WA", "WI", "WV", "WY"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("0", 
"1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", 
"13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
"24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
"35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
"46", "47", "48", "49", "50"), data_types = c("C", "C", "C"))
```

Comment: In your example data, where is the "ID_2" column?

Comment: @zx8754 sorry, I've just edited the post. Same problem :(

Comment: We need to have 2 datasets for testing, could you provide the 2nd dataframe, too?

Comment: @zx8754 I've already edited again.

Comment: You don't have "Cases" column in the second dataframe. Are you trying to merge on "State name" ?

Comment: @zx8754 What should I put(   x= "",by.y=""?)  in order to visualize a map with the cases of Covid by state? .

Comment: We already have State name and the counts for Cases. Why do we need to merge?

Comment: To merge you need to have one column in each data frame match and in this case it is the state names.  Since the column names don't match you need adjust for that by specifying the matching columns with `by.x = "STATE_NAME", by.y ="State"`